# $1\cdot3\cdot5 \cdots (p - 2) = (-1)^{m+k+1} \pmod p$, and $2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(p - 1) = ( -1)^{m +k} \pmod p$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that if $p$ is a prime having the form $4k + 3$, and if $m$ is the number of quadratic residues less than $\frac p2$, then we have

$$1\cdot3\cdot5 \cdots (p - 2) = (-1)^{m+k+1} \pmod p, \text{ and } 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(p - 1) = ( -1)^{m +k} \pmod p.$$

I am stuck with the problem....Help Needed.

Comment: @hardy the that is 1 not l

Comment: see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_of_Eisenstein.27s_lemma

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \{-1,1\}$, where $\phi(n) = 1$ is a homomorphism given by $1$ if $n$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $-1$ if not.

Now consider $1 \cdot 3 \cdots (p-2)$. Now switch every number $x$ bigger than $\frac p2$ to $(p-x)$. Eventually as you will make $\frac{p-3}{4} = k$ changes we have that:

$$1 \cdot 3 \cdots (p-2) = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \cdot (-1)^k$$

It's fairly easy to notice that $\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$ is equal to either $1$ or $-1$ modulo $p$, so the sum is equal to $-1$ or $1$. Also let's note that $\phi(1) = 1$ and $\phi(-1) = -1$, so therefore it's enough to see whether $ \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!$ is sent by $\phi$ to $1$ or $-1$. But by the definition of $\phi$ we have that $\phi\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! = (-1)^t$, where $t$ is the number of non-equadratic residues modulo $p$ and less than $\frac{p}{2}$. As there are odd amount of numbers less than $\frac{p}{2}$ we have that $t$ and $m$ have a different parity, hence $(-1)^t = (-1)^{m+1}$ and:

$$1 \cdot 3 \cdots (p-2) = \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \cdot (-1)^k \equiv (-1)^{k+t} \equiv (-1)^{k+m+1} \pmod p$$

Similar reasoning yields the wanted proof for the second part.

Comment: what is $m$ ? and please rename $\phi$ as $\chi$ (\chi) ${}{}{}$

Comment: @user1952009 The number of quadratic residues less than $\frac p2$, as stated in the question.

Comment: your answer is very hard to follow. you should write that $\chi$ is multiplicative, and that $1 \cdot 3 \cdots (p-2) \equiv \left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)! \cdot (-1)^k \equiv (-1)^{k+t}  \equiv (-1)^k\chi((-1)^{t} )$ $ \equiv (-1)^k  \chi(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!) \equiv (-1)^k  \prod_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \chi(n) \equiv (-1)^k (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}-m} \bmod p$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see where the problem is. We have that $t = \frac{p-1}2 - m$, as $\frac{p-1}2$ is odd we have that m and t have different parity. The parity is all we need to determine whether it's -1 or 1

Comment: I didn't say there is problem, just that it is not obvious what you are showing until we get everything (your proof reduces to what I wrote, and it has many steps..)

Comment: And for $\frac{p-1}{2}! \equiv \pm 1 \bmod p$ you meant [once we know $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \bmod p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) and using that $ -(\frac{p-1}{2}!)^2 \equiv - \prod_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} n (p-n) = (p-1)! \bmod p$